# Modern way of inheriting from set

Tags: python, set

I have been taught that it is dangerous to inherit from `dict`, but we should inherit from `collections.UserDict`.
Is there any symmetry with `set`? I want a set-like class with some instance variables. I've read about abstract classes but in old posts.
What is the modern approach to creating set-like objects?

Comment: [_"The need for this class has been partially supplanted by the ability to subclass directly from `dict`..."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userdict-objects) Also note https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use a dictionary as a set, by considering only the keys, and using dummy values (e.g., `None`). This way you can inherit from `UserDict` without concerns.

Alternatively, you can inherit from `typing.MutableSet`

Comment: Alternatively, you can just inherit from `set`. There's never really been an argument *against* inheriting from the built-in types (once doing so was actually possible), so much as there are arguments against getting rid of `UserDict` completely.

Comment: Didn't get your point. OP have asked for the best practice to inherit from `set`, this is in order to preserve its functionality while add some of its own. Also he explained its concerns from inherit from built-in types (and rightly so) and mentioned alternatives such as `UserDict` which is meant exactly to this purpose. Therefore, I proposed similar and current approaches for doing so, knowing that if he would like to inherit from built-in types he wouldn't post this question

Comment: I'm saying there's no reason to be concerned about inheriting directly from `set`. `UserDict` was added when it was simply not *possible* to inherit from `dict`, not because it wasn't safe. Once that restriction was lifted, it was decided that there may be some reasons to continue using `UserDict`, but "safety" was not one of them. There's nothing dangerous about inheriting from `set`, and no reason to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to inherit from set is to just do it.

```
class MySet(set):
    ...
```

It's not that it was ever *dangerous* to inherit from `dict`; in earlier versions of Python, it simply wasn't *possible*. As a workaround, the `UserDict` class was added the standard library. It provided a class with a `dict`-like mapping interface, but was not a `dict` itself: instead, it stored its data in an ordinary `dict`.

When new-style classes were introduce in Python 2.2, the restriction on inheriting from `dict` and other built-in classes was lifted. The documentation for `UserDict` explains that the class was not deprecated because it remained more *convenient* in some cases to continue to use the wrapper, but it is largely unnecessary.